# Full details for jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler- Can I Used script language JAVA?

Tags: jmeter

I want to write some selenium script using jp@gc - WebDriver Sampler . Here I used Script Language JAVA. Can Here I used main function ? or is it  supported only JUnit? Can I write a script in TestNG?
Already I wrote one script for that I got error" when used (driver.get("https://opensource-demo.orangehrmlive.com"); )

```
java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: data
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:618)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:508)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:457)
at com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler.sample(WebDriverSampler.java:90)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:638)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no `java` language either in WebDriver Sampler or in [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting), when you choose `java` in the language drop-down the script will be evaluated by [Beanshell](https://beanshell.github.io/) interpreter. If you're looking for the closest to Java syntax - go for `groovy`
2. There is no need to define an "entry point", the [interpreter reads the script at once](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/scripting/scripting-languages-and-java.htm#JSJSG107) and executes line-by-line. You can have classes if you want. You can have `main()` function if you want but you will need to explicitly call it.
3. There a pre-defined [WebDriver](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/) instance `WDS.browser` so the minimal test would be something like:

   ```
   WDS.sampleResult.sampleStart()
   WDS.browser.get('http://example.com')
   WDS.sampleResult.sampleEnd()
   ```

   You may find [The WebDriver Sampler: Your Top 10 Questions Answered](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/webdriver-sampler-your-top-ten-questions-answered) article useful.